# Adding together similar columns into one column SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to show the counts of a table of records based on a trackid.

A few of the entries in my ToTransaction column are very similar: Toshi-A,Toshi-B,Toshi-C, Tosan, Toki, Toto

What I want to do in my query is to show all the Toshi's in one row, while still giving Tosan, Toki, and Toto their own rows.

```
Route  ToTransaction  Count
 F43   Toshi          100
 F43   Tosan          200
 F43   Toki           75
 F43   Toto           125
```

Instead of

```
Route  ToTransaction  Count
 F43   Toshi-A          35
 F43   Toshi-B          25
 F43   Toshi-C          22
 F43   Toshi-D          18  
 F43   Tosan          200
 F43   Toki           75
 F43   Toto           125


SELECT Route, ToTransaction, count(TrackID) as 'Count' from TestDB
group by Route, ToTransaction
```

Comment: You have to pick one. `mysql` or `sql-server` which dbms you are using.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Pick one.

Comment: SQLServer is what I'm using.

Comment: is there another row like `Toshi-xx` or `Toshi-xxx` instead of `Toshi-x` ?

Comment: Toshi is the only one that has multiple variants

Comment: If so, the answer by `Fenisitil` should've works..

Comment: was unable to do if() in sql server. Also does this method actually sum together all the rows with "Toshi-X" or does it just rename the row "Toshi"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT IF(SUBSTR(ToTransaction,1,5)="Toshi","Toshi",ToTransaction) as "Trans",
COUNT(TracID) as "Count" from TestDB
GROUP BY Trans;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use always "-" as seperator and the character count before the "-" character is dynamic you can use substring_index :

For MySQL :

```
SELECT substring_index(ToTransaction,'-',1) as "Trans",
COUNT(TracID) as "Count" from TestDB 
GROUP BY 1;
```

For MSSQL (I Couldn't try but It should work) :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',ToTransaction) > 1 
   THEN LEFT(ToTransaction,CHARINDEX('-',ToTransaction)-1) 
   ELSE ToTransaction 
END as "Trans",
COUNT(TracID) as "Count" from TestDB GROUP BY Trans;
```

Comment: Is this true for SQLSERVER?

Comment: Actually it works fine on mysql. for mssql something like this should work : SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',ToTransaction) > 1 THEN LEFT(ToTransaction,CHARINDEX('-',ToTransaction)-1) ELSE ToTransaction END as "Trans",
COUNT(TracID) as "Count" from TestDB 
GROUP BY Trans;

Comment: All this does is filter out the letters, I want to wrap the Tosh-A,Toshi-B,Toshi-C,Toshi-D all into one record, and still have my separate records for Tosan Toki and Toto. Is this approachable in SQL Server?

Comment: Can you add the result that you get from the query above ? I don't have Mssql to test the query